# Can I ask people on Meta to point me to specific SO question/answer, if I'm not able to find it myself

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I'm looking for specific answer to some question I think I've saw on SO, but I wasn't able to find it by myself.

Is it OK to ask people on Meta (or, maybe, on SO) for pointers?

Comment: You are looking for an existing answer on SO?

Comment: try the chat room, if there happens to be an active one for your topic

Comment: Well, I would say we're not a search engine, so I don't see it as on-topic for Meta. Too localized really.

Comment: +1 for using another alternative different than opening your browser in incognito mode and post the question regardless if there are dups (lazy people often do this to make others search the duplicates for them)

Comment: @ajax333221 Thanks for that tip :p (Though I think SO requires registration now, right?)

Comment: @Bart the fact that I don't know the answer to your question makes me feel proud of myself

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, for existing (I believe) answer. Ok, I'll try chat room for that. Thanks!